# Intent for app details page

Tags: android, android-intent

My app relies heavily on a database for data and sometimes the database won't copy correctly, gets corrupted, or just throws a generic strop. Clearing the app data and then reopening the app seems to work well, but it's quite a chore to ask my users to dig through the settings pages, and I'm looking for a way to quickly get to the app details page (which shows the uninstall, move to SD, clear data etc.)

I've found the [`Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS) Intent action but get an `ActivityNotFoundException` when I try to launch it as described on my Desire Z. Can anyone help me out how to properly sort this?

Thanks

EDIT: As noted in the answers, this is only API9 and above, the code I now use if anyone wants it is below. Believe it works on API3 and above.

```
try {

    Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    i.setData(Uri.parse("package:com.espian.formulae"));
    startActivity(i);

} catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) { 

    Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APPLICATIONS_SETTINGS);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

Comment: That intent is only available as of API Level 9 (2.3). Does your Desire Z have 2.3 installed?

Comment: No it doesn't, didn't realise it was a level 9. :( that's really annoying but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll post it as answer here in addition to my comment. That intent is only available as of API Level 9 (2.3). The Desire Z doesn't have 2.3... yet. ;)

Answer (score 11):

I know that this is way too late answer but it may help someone. Based on the platform (froyo) source I make one function that opens a specific package's settings page. It works in the emulator but I never tried on a real device. I don't know if it works on API < 8 either.

Here it is:

```
public boolean startFroyoInstalledAppDetailsActivity(String packagename) {
    boolean result = false;

    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.InstalledAppDetails");
    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.putExtra("pkg", packagename);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    try {
        cx.startActivity(i);
        result = true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Based on your code I also make a Gingerbread version which works on real devices with API levels 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 and 15 but it can be called safely from API 8 however in this case it will return false.

Here it is:

```
public boolean startGingerbreadInstalledAppDetailsActivity(String packagename) {
    boolean result = false;

    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction("android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS");
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packagename));
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    try {
        cx.startActivity(i);
        result = true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: The second code block is what you want if the API level is higher than 8.